# Desktop won't boot to Windows 10 (including safe mode & recovery media USB) but will boot to Ubuntu

Tags: windows-10, boot

My desktop (all AMD parts) fails to boot to Windows 10 normally, safe mode, or using Microsoft's media creation tool on a USB. In all case, the Windows logo will pop up and the loading circle will appear, but within a few seconds the screen will go full black and the computer will restart. When trying to boot normally, it attempts to go to 'Automatic Repair' but fails.

I do have Ubuntu on another partition which I am able to boot to and use normally. I tried tools to repair my Windows from within Ubuntu and I believe Windows is stuck in a 'hibernation' state.

I have tried updating the BIOS to the latest version, as well as changing secure boot, boot mode, and CSM inside the BIOS. I believe my issue was caused by taking out the power cable too early during shutdown.

Comment: Please try to [skip hibernation mode](https://superuser.com/questions/594263/how-to-skip-hibernation-mode-and-boot-into-windows-directly) and boot directly into Windows. Hopefully you would be able to remove hibernation image.

Comment: @derloopkat I've been unable to skip hibernation mode using both methods mentioned in that post (holding down space or F8). Maybe the keys for this have changed in Windows 10 but I'm struggling to find info on this.

Comment: If you can boot to Ubuntu, according to [this post](https://superuser.com/a/242663/302850) you would be able to [delete hiberfil.sys](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/15140/what-is-hiberfil.sys-and-how-do-i-delete-it/) from there.